# reading bmc280 & tsl2561

Tags: i2c, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am trying to read [`bme280`](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bme280) & [`tsl2561`](https://www.adafruit.com/product/439) on Pi Zero. I have connected `bme280` to Pi Zero on `Pin 3-I2C.1 SDA` & `Pin 5-I2C.1 SCL` and was able to read the data over `i2c` following [these](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.bme280/) instruction. Then connected `tsl2561` to `Pin 27-I2C.0 SDA` & `Pin 28-I2C.0 SCL`.

When I list I2C connected devices with `ls /dev/*i2c*` it shows me just `/dev/i2c-1`. Why I am seeing just one device ?

Output of `i2cdetect -y 1` was

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --
```

when I tried `i2cdetect -y 0` got

```
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0' or `/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory
```

Also tried to run [TSL2561.py](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/TSL2561/blob/master/Python/TSL2561.py) but got following error

```
$ python TSL2561.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TSL2561.py", line 16, in <module>
    bus.write_byte_data(0x39, 0x00 | 0x80, 0x03)
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

Are Physical pin `27` & `28` are `Pin 27-I2C.0 SDA` & `Pin 28-I2C.0 SCL` respectively on **Pi Zero W** ? If yes what I need to do to activate them to read tsl2561 through them ?

Kernel Version : Linux pod01 4.14.79+ #1159 Sun Nov 4 17:28:08 GMT 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I²C.0 is reserved for system use.

It is only on the header for use by HATs.

Comment: How can I user other GPIO for I2C, since `I2C.1` already consumed ?

Comment: @roy you can connect many I²C devices to the interface, provided they have unique addresses.